# Validation of survey input on Mechanical Turk

Tags: javascript, html, mechanicalturk

I am using the Amazon Mechanical Turk template to create a survey (HIT) and would like to have the survey questions required. I have three groups of radio buttons within the survey template that I would like to have all filled out before the form is submitted. I need help with the validation syntax.

Here's one group of my radio buttons:

```
<div class="radio"><label><strong><input name="ABCD Test" type="radio" value="1" /></strong>Yes</label></div>
<div class="radio"><label><input name="ABCD Test" type="radio" value="2" />No</label></div>
<div class="radio"><label><input name="ABCD Test" type="radio" value="3" />Not sure</label></div>
```

I found the code below on stack overflow but I am struggling with the syntax on how to make use of it in regards to my specific radio buttons above. Can someone please help with the syntax to

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
window.onload = function() {document.getElementById('submitButton').setAttribute('onclick', 'return validateForm()'); }



function validateForm() {
if (validate)
return true;
else
return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can anyone please help with the syntax for the above problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please add jQuery and run, should work

```js
//javascript //included jQuery
function validateForm() {
var vali = $('.radio').find(':checked').length>0;
  if (vali)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="" onsubmit="return validateForm();" method="GET">
<div class="radio"><label><strong><input name="ABCD Test" type="radio" value="1" /></strong>Yes</label></div>
<div class="radio"><label><input name="ABCD Test" type="radio" value="2" />No</label></div>
<div class="radio"><label><input name="ABCD Test" type="radio" value="3" />Not sure</label></div>
<input id=submitButton type=submit value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: this hasn't worked. It still submits without any input.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
<script>
    function validateRadioButtons()
    {
        var radios = document.getElementsByName('ABCD Test')

        for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
            if (radios[i].checked) {
                alert(radios[i].value);
                return true;
            }
        }

        alert("You must check at least one of the radio buttons before submitting.");
        return false;
    }
</script>

<div class="radio"><label><strong><input name="ABCD Test" type="radio" value="1" /></strong>Yes</label></div>
<div class="radio"><label><input name="ABCD Test" type="radio" value="2" />No</label></div>
<div class="radio"><label><input name="ABCD Test" type="radio" value="3" />Not sure</label></div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="validateRadioButtons();" />
```